# Testing text node in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have the following mix-content element:

```
<firstElement type="random">text1<secondElement>random_value</secondElement>text2</firstElement>
```

I want to make a `for-each` loop on `<firstElement>` child nodes with a nested `if` condition, for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="some test">
<xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I write a `test` that selects only the text nodes of `<firstElement>`?

I have tried with `text()`, but it only works for the child text node of the contextual node and `self::text()` doesn't seem to be a proper Xpath. I also tried to use XSLT 2.0 `instance of` to test against `xs:string` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I write a test that selects only the text nodes of
>   `<firstElement>`?

It is really difficult to understand your question:

First, a test does not *select* anything - I suppose you mean you want the test to *pass* text nodes only.

Next, when you do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
```

you are selecting *element* nodes only - so any subsequent test that passes *text* nodes only will always return false.

It's also not clear why you need to select any nodes that are **not** text nodes in the first place, and then test them and pass only text nodes. But supposing that's really what you want to do, you can do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="firstElement">
    <output>
        <!-- select all child nodes --> 
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
            <!-- pass only text nodes --> 
            <xsl:if test=". instance of text()">
                <xsl:copy/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

This returns:

```
<output>text1text2</output>
```

which is the same result returned by the much simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="firstElement">
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

---

> I have tried with `text()`, but it only works for the child text node of the contextual node and `self::text()` doesn't seem to be a proper Xpath.

I am not sure why you think so.

```
<xsl:if test="self::text()">
```

works just as well - and has the advantage of being backward-compatible with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Maybe your difficulty to understand my question comes from a bad design choice. I want to perform different transformations for text nodes and for other nodes inside `firstElement` and only inside that particular element. I achieved this by writing two different templates: one for the text nodes that are children of firstElement and one for the other elements children of firstElement. But for the sake of clarity, I thought it would be better to have both transformations inside only one template. It's why I wanted to use a for-each loop with nested if condition.

Comment: Thanks, I used `. instance of text()` and it works fine. Could you help a little bit further? I don't fully understand the behavior of the `for-each` loop here. When I choose the element nodes, e.g. with an `if` statement, using `apply-templates` only copy the textual content of the element. I need to specify `apply-templates select="."` in order to apply the matching templates. Why?

Comment: It makes very little sense to use `apply-templates select="."` within `xsl:for-each`. If you want to apply a template to the selected nodes, then apply it directly, using `apply templates` **instead of** `xsl:for-each`. In any case, the default selection for `apply-templates` is the child nodes of the context node.